# VB6 Timeout the function if no response

Tags: vb6

I have a function within a VB6 app that forces the program to be inaccessible. Sometimes when an error happens within the function the end-user wouldn't receive a result and might still think that something is happening in the background.

Due to that I was thinking of adding a timeout function. I know that function should return result within 1-2 seconds and if not there was an error so we have to break the function and return an error.

How can this "timeout" be achieved in VB6?

Comment: You are more likely to get an answer when you post the relevant code with you question. Without your code persons attempting to answer have to guess at what you're doing, and can only give general answers.

Comment: What is it that causes the delay? Is it a very long calculation which takes a lot of runtime, or is it waiting for another computer in a network to respond?

Comment: Function is from DLL, its waiting for response from another computer. I would be interested in some type of wrapper of some sort that would time it out after 10 seconds if no response was found. A basic example of code: "Call CheckConnection()" - when run have to get response from another computer without it function keeps searching.

Comment: You may be out of luck with VB6. The call to the DLL is 'in-process' and so  the thread is blocked and cannot be interrupted.

Comment: I see, so it has to be done within C++, in which DLL is written in.

Comment: That's my guess. With C++ you might be able to use another thread and have VB6 poll some sort of result indication and give up if it takes too long.

Comment: A synchronous call is a synchronous call.  One a thread is in there no other thread is going to pull it out.  So no help from C++, or angels or leprechauns either.  At best you'd have to make the call on a worker thread and kill it when it takes too long about returning.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the sample below will help, it assumes a `Timer` control on your form named `Timer1`

```
Private Function TestFunction() As Boolean

    On Error GoTo TestFunctionErrHandler

    Me.Timer1.Interval = 1000 ' set time to fire one time per second
    ' code for (function should return result within 1-2 seconds) here

    Exit Function

TestFunctionErrHandler:
    ' code for error condition here

End Function

Private Sub Timer1_Timer()
    Static seconds As Integer

    seconds = seconds + 1

    If seconds >= 2 Then
        ' code for (forces the program to be inaccessible) here
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: May as well just set the Interval to 2000 and be done with it.  But even then the blocking call will prevent the Timer event handler from ever being called.